# Android Emulator does not work on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, react-native, android-emulator, ubuntu-16.04

I use an Acer Aspire E1-530 with an Intel 2117U Processor and 6GB of RAM.

I followed the steps given in the [React Native Website](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) to install React Native and Android Studio 2.3, and also installed KVM as given in [this Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation). Android Studio launches without a problem, and I was successfully able to setup an AVD, but when I launch the AVD, a small window shows up for a brief second and then disappears. I also tried running `emulator` from `~/Android/Sdk/tools`, but it shows this error:

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  55
  Current serial number in output stream:  54
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  55
  Current serial number in output stream:  54
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  39
  Current serial number in output stream:  40
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When I run `emulator-check accl`, I get the following output:

```
accel:
0
KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.
accel
```

Comment: Do you have discrete graphics?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace emulator's libstdc++.so with your own:

```
mv ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6{,.bak}
mv ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6.0.18 {,.bak}
ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so  ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/
```

Comment: any clarification on this answer?

Answer (score 2):

Run emulator from terminal

> $ emulator -use-system-libs -avd YOUR_VIRTUAL_DEVICE_NAME