# I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 and when I try to install Android Studio and run my virtual device, it gives these errors

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio-3.0

Why can't I run this Android virtual device on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)?

```
2:24 PM    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

2:24 PM    Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so

2:24 PM    Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing

2:24 PM    Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965

2:24 PM    Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so

2:24 PM    Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing

2:24 PM    Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965

2:24 PM    Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so

2:24 PM    Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

2:24 PM    Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

2:24 PM    Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)

2:24 PM    Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)

2:24 PM    Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0

2:24 PM    Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  39

2:24 PM    Emulator: Current serial number in output stream:  40

2:24 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

2:24 PM    Gradle build finished in 5s 92ms
```

Comment: Looks like the same problem as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911302/cannot-launch-emulator-on-linux-ubuntu-15-10 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872128/android-emulator-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-16-10.  Try solutions given to those questions.

Comment: Did my answer below solve your issue?

Answer (score 33):

These are the exact steps you need to follow to solve the emulator issue:

1) Change directory:

```
$ cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
```

2) Create symbolic link to library:

```
$ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

3)on the same directory:

```
$ ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

That should fix it!

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, most of the answers I kept seeing were point at ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++ instead of ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++ which did not exists in my case: Android Studio 3.0.1 thank you for sharing!